# повторная привязка QUdpSocket

Tags: qt, qt5

создании серверного UDP-сокета делаю привязку к адресу с помощью bind

через некоторое время пытаюсь повторно bind к другому адресу

выдает QNativeSocketEngine::bind() was not called in QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState

что это и как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ошибка "QNativeSocketEngine::bind() was not called in
> QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState" обычно возникает, когда пытаетесь
> вызвать метод bind() для QUdpSocket в состоянии UnconnectedState,
> когда сокет не подключен. Вы должны вызвать bind() только после
> создания сокса или после закрытия предыдущего соединения.
>
> Если вы хотите перепривязать сокс к другому адресу или порту, вам
> сначала нужно вызвать close() для закрытия текущего соединения, а
> затем bind() с новым адресом. Примерно так:

QUdpSocket udpSocket;
udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::Any, 1234); // Привязываем сокс к адресу и порту

// Позже, когда вы хотите изменить адрес
udpSocket.close(); // Закрываем текущее соединение
udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::Any, 5678); // Привязываем сокс к новому адресу и порту

> Этот код сначала привязывает сокс к адресу и порту 1234, а затем
> закрывает текущее соединение и привязывает его к новому адресу и порту
> 5678.
>
> Убедитесь, что вызываете close() перед вызовом bind() с новыми
> параметрами, и это должно решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Спасибо! помогло!

Comment: Обращайся *))))